# How do i send a value from my first form to my main form in c#

Tags: c#, forms

Im making a little log in interface and im trying to send the user id after a succesfull login to my main form for safekeeping. I know how to do it from main to a secondary but i have no idea how to do it back. as im not creating a new Form main = new form();

```
public void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserClass existingUser = new UserClass();
        existingUser.username = tbUsername.Text;
        existingUser.password = tbPassword.Text;
        result = databaseConnector.LogUSerIn(existingUser.username, existingUser.password);
        if (result == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There aren't any registerd users with these credentials. Please try again or register below");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Log in succesfull, Happy browsing!");
            //Return value to Main form. 
            LogIn.ActiveForm.Close();

        }
```

I would like the value result be send back to my main form. ive browsed the internet for about half an hour now and i only see from MAIN to SECONDARY but i can never find the reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a similar way like the [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples) does it.

Create a public property `UserId` in your login form and set the user id when the user logs in.

You can now access this property `UserId` in your main form after the ShowDialog() method of your login form has been called.

I can look something like this in your main form:

```
var loginForm = new LoginForm();
loginForm.ShowDialog();
var userId = loginForm.UserId;
// do something with the userId. maybe store it in a property of your main form.
```